# Java ENUM problem

Tags: java, enums

I have two `Enum`s as follows:

```
enum Connector {
    AND, OR, XOR;
}

enum Component {
    ACTIVITY
}
```

Now, I have a variable named `follower` in a class `Event`. This variable (`follower`) can have (and should have) value from either of the above two `Enum`s.

So, What datatype should I give to the `follower` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Enum follower;
```

And you can make both enums implement the same interface, for example `Follower`, and let the field be:

```
private Enum<? extends Follower> follower;
```

But you'd better redesign the whole thing, it doesn't feel right this way.

Comment: Can Enums have parent-child relationship just like classes? If they can, then I cam make both the enums (Connector and Component) as child of a parent enum and specified that as the datatype of the `follower` variable

Comment: an enum is essentialyl `public YourEnum extends Enum<YourEnum>`, you you can't extend anything else. But you can implement interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Declare an interface for the `follower` field.

```
public interface Follower {
    // any methods
}
```

And have both the enums implement that interface.

```
public enum Connector implements Follower {
    AND, OR, XOR;
}


enum Component implements Follower {
    ACTIVITY
}
```

Then you can declare your field:

```
Follower follower = Connector.OR;
```

Or

```
Follower follower = Component.ACTIVITY;
```

This has a couple distinct advantage over declaring the field as an `Enum<? extends Follower>` (that I can think of). With this way you are free to add methods to the `Follower` interface without having to modify fields in the future, whereas you have no control over the `Enum` type, so if you decided that `Follower`s needed a method, you would have to change the declaration in every place. This may never be the case with your scenario, but with so little cost to use this way, it's good defensive practice.

A second, slightly less important advantage, which is more about taste: it avoids the generics in the type which, when you include wildcards, can become less readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an interface for both enums:

```
interface X {}

enum Connector implements X{
    AND, OR, XOR;
}

enum Component implements X{
    ACTIVITY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new Class called Follower.  I'm not sure a single variable should have two different types even if it's possible.

I tend to think of Enums as primitive data types and your question would be like asking how do I make a variable be either int or long.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to have follower of type java.lang.Enum. It is parent of all enums in java.
So following code works just fine.

package com.test;

enum NewEnum {
    one, two;
}

enum Another {
    three, four;
}

public class TestMe {

```
static Enum num = NewEnum.one;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(num.toString());
    num = Another.three;
    System.out.println(num.toString());

}
```

}